# Slickgrid + DataView - edit cellsHi

Tags: knockout.js, slickgrid

I am using SlickGrid with a combination of `Dataview`, `Overlays` and `HeaderFilter` all of them set up in (what I believe is) a standard way:

```
var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView({ inlineFilters: true });

var grid = new Slick.Grid(element, dataView, parameters options);
// setup dataview:
// hook onRowCountChanged, onRowsChanged
// beginUpdate, setItems, setFilter, setFilterArgs, endUpdate

var filterPlugin = new Ext.Plugins.HeaderFilter({});
// setup header filter - onFilterApplied and onCommand
grid.registerPlugin(filterPlugin);

var overlayPlugin = new Ext.Plugins.Overlays({});
// setup overlay plugin - onFillUpDown
grid.registerPlugin(overlayPlugin);
```

In my parameters, I set `editor` to `Slick.Editors.Text`.

When I click/double-click a cell, nothing happens.

I tried to disabled all the plugin and use the data directly without the data view - to no avail - I am not able to edit any cell.

I hooked the `onClick`, `onDblClick` and `onBeforeEditCell` and I see the former two fired but not the latter.

Note: I am using slickgrid 2.1.0 along with slickgrid-bootstrap (and I am reluctant to change any of these since the project is very old and I am not sure how the dependencies will align if I start to change). I also use knockout.js (3.2) and jquery (1.12.4)

Any hints as to what I may be doing wrong? How to troubleshoot/diagnose the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a start, check out www.slickgrid.net

The MLeibman repository is essentially abandoned. Try the [6pac](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid) repo, which has patches for the latest jQuery/Bootstrap versions (disclosure: this is my repo).

If anyone can link to www.slickgrid.net, here or in blog posts, whatever, that would be great. The original repo still has a lot more search traction, and given its status, that causes problems.

Comment: Thanks - I actually run into 6pac repo late last night. As for the problem - a colleague pointed out I omitted `editable: true` from the grid options...

Answer (score 0):

Turn out the issue was missing `editable` property in the options. Without it, the other settings were not effective and the issue is not related to DataView and the plugins.

Note in the [documentation](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Grid-Options) the editable property defaults to false.